# How to strip HTML tags, CSS from a string?

Tags: php, strip

I have string such as

```
<p>
    <style type="text/css">
P { margin-bottom: 0.21cm; direction: ltr; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); }P.western { font-family: "Times New Roman",serif; font-size: 12pt; }P.cjk { font-family: "Arial Unicode MS",sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; }P.ctl { font-family: "Tahoma"; font-size: 12pt; }    </style>
</p>
<p align="CENTER" class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm">
    <font size="5" style="font-size: 20pt"><u><b> TEXT I WANT TO GET </b></u></font></p>
```

How can i strip html, css and get only text?

Im aware of `strip_tags()`, and I can write function with `preg_replace`, but is there a working solution for php?
Thanks.

Comment: You could use a DOM parser.

Comment: what do you mean with "working solution for php"? strip_tags and a preg_replace regex will work in php. do you want to strip php-tags out of the code? even for this a regular expression could be fine

Comment: I know strip_tags and preg_replace, i was just looking for some already made solution which actually strips all html tags and all css tags and give you clean text

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use:

```
<?php

$text = '<p>
    <style type="text/css">
P { margin-bottom: 0.21cm; direction: ltr; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); }P.western { font-family: "Times New Roman",serif; font-size: 12pt; }P.cjk { font-family: "Arial Unicode MS",sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; }P.ctl { font-family: "Tahoma"; font-size: 12pt; }    </style>
</p>
<p align="CENTER" class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm">
    <font size="5" style="font-size: 20pt"><u><b> TEXT I WANT TO GET </b></u></font></p>';

$text = strip_tags($text,"<style>");

$substring = substr($text,strpos($text,"<style"),strpos($text,"</style>")+2);

$text = str_replace($substring,"",$text);
$text = str_replace(array("\t","\r","\n"),"",$text);
$text = trim($text);

echo $text;

?>
```

Comment: @Salim it remove all the html tags as well.I need to keep it as it is but removed css only.

Comment: The answer is incorrect, see [here](https://repl.it/repls/MemorableEmbellishedObjectdatabase).   
It returns ">     TEXT I WANT TO GET "

Comment: @Raham, just add whatever tags you don't want removed to `$text = strip_tags($text,"<style>")` like this, `$text = strip_tags($text,"<style><p><b><strong>")`

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that occurrences of style tag are removed and all whitespace reduced to a single space:

```
$text = '<p>
<style type="text/css">
P { margin-bottom: 0.21cm; direction: ltr; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); }P.western { font- 
family: "Times New Roman",serif; font-size: 12pt; }P.cjk { font-family: "Arial Unicode 
MS",sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; }P.ctl { font-family: "Tahoma"; font-size: 12pt; }    
</style>
</p>
<p align="CENTER" class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm">
    <font size="5" style="font-size: 20pt"><u><b> TEXT I WANT TO GET </b></u></font> 
</p>
<style>a { color: red}</style>';

$text = strip_tags($text, '<style>');
$start = strpos($text, '<style');
// All of occurrences of <style>.
while ($start !== false) {
    $end = strpos($text, '</style>');
    if (!$text) {
        break;
    }
    $diff = $end - $start + strlen('</style>');
    $substring = substr($text, $start, $diff);
    $text = str_replace($substring, '', $text);
    $start = strpos($text, '<style');
}

// Remaining <style> if any.
$text = strip_tags($text);

// Remove all new lines and tabs and use a space instead.
$text = str_replace(["\n", "\r", "\t"], ' ', $text);

// Trim left and right.
$text = trim($text);

// Remove all spaces that have more than one occurrence.
$text = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $text);

echo $text;
```

Here's the [output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e100b82db52bfa97657c8057f31e5fa962bf2c4c).

Answer (score 1):

This function is modified to keep line breaks.

```
function strip($text,$keepLines=true)
{
    if($keepLines) $text=str_replace(array('</p>','<br/>','<br>'),array("</p> \n","<br/> \n","<br> \n"),$text);
    $text = strip_tags($text,"<style>");

    if(strpos($text,"<style")!==false && strpos($text,"</style>")!==false)
    {
        $substring = substr($text,strpos($text,"<style"),strpos($text,"</style>")+8);
        $text = str_replace($substring,'',$text);
    }

    if(!$keepLines)
    {
        $text = str_replace(array("\t","\r","\n"),"",$text);
        $text = preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$text);
    }
    else
    {
        $text = str_replace('  ',' ',$text);
    }   
    return trim($text);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me .

```
function strip_tag_css($text){


    $text = strip_tags($text,"<style>");

    $substring = substr($text,strpos($text,"<style"),strpos($text,"</style>")+2);

    $text = str_replace($substring,"",$text);
    $text = str_replace(array("\t","\r","\n"),"",$text);
    $text = trim($text);

    return $text;
}


$bodymensage = str_replace('  ','',html_entity_decode( strip_tag_css(strip_tags($message)), ENT_QUOTES, "utf8" ));
```

Comment: This is incorrect because `$substring = substr($text,strpos($text,"<style"),strpos($text,"</style>")+2);` does not return the correct substring.