# Converting HTML code to plain TEXT with formatting available to text-files

Tags: php, dom, strip-tags, text-formatting, html-rendering

The task: taking HTML page and keeping only text from it with formatting available for simple text: so if there was `<br>` tag I'd like to convert it to /r/n, if there was a table - I'd like to keep the initial structure of this table in the resulting text and so on.

There are built-in PHP function `strip_tags()` which is not really fits my requirements as it will keep the contents of styles and scripts and will not keep the formatting deleting `<br>`, `<table>` and other tags.

I also have read the [stack question 'strip html,css from string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587830/strip-html-css-from-string) but there's no answer I'm looking for.

Essentially I'm looking for a way to render an HTML page to TXT file (with no links and images). Is it possible? Is there any libraries doing this thing?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do with this is, you can do a reverse Markdown. There are a lot of implementation of HTML to Markdown, which does the job you want. They just convert the HTML to text, including the breaks, etc.

One such implementation is [html2markdown](https://github.com/kates/html2markdown). It uses NodeJS and you just need to add this:

```
html2markdown("<h1>Hello markdown!</h1>")
```

At least, this will strip the tags and give you the result as text, that can be easily markdown-stripped, coz it has less number of characters, say `#`s and `---`s.

There is also one more implementation of html2markdown in PHP in [GitHub](https://github.com/nickcernis/html2markdown/). The syntax is again simple:

```
$html = "<h3>Quick, to the Batpoles!</h3>";
$markdown = new HTML_To_Markdown($html);
```

And this returns you with:

```
echo $markdown; // ==> ### Quick, to the Batpoles!
```

This plugin has an ability to strip the tags too:

```
$html = '<span>Turnips!</span>';
$markdown = new HTML_To_Markdown($html, array('strip_tags' => true)); // $markdown now contains "Turnips!"
```